# Org mode C-c C-c to display inline image

Tags: org-mode

For below org mode code example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file test.png
Alice -> Bob: synchronous call
Alice ->> Bob: asynchronous call
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:test.png]]
```

After press C-c C-c, the result is as above. If I need to show it as image, I have to run "M-x org-display-inline-image" command.

Is it possible to combine the "C-c C-c" and "M-x org-display-inline-image" together? It's better to still use "C-c C-c" shortcut.

Comment: If you are just looking to always have the image inlined, you can put `#+STARTUP: inlineimages` somewhere in your org file. (And `C-c C-c` that so you don't need to reopen your buffer)

Comment: @Archenoth Actually my cause is: 1. Update source code. 2. Press C-c C-c to execute the code. 3. Output is text but not image. I wish everytime after press C-c C-c, I can get the image displayed inline. Your suggestion works if user didn't change the code.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! I had forgotten I had already done something about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not redefine `C-c C-c` in Org mode then? Use this keybinding. Put it in your emacs init.el file and restart emacs:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
  (lambda () (interactive) (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
                           (org-display-inline-image)))
```

> addendum: is this global or local?

Local to org-mode only.

Comment: Sounds like return a error: Wrong type argument: listp, t. BTW, will this redefine globally or just for org mode?

Comment: @beetlej try tweak it as below: (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
    (org-display-inline-images)))

Comment: local only, also fixed the error typo in the answer above

Comment: For me it's working with `org-display-inline-images`.

Answer (score 27):

There is both a hook for evaluating code blocks (`org-babel-after-execute-hook`), and a function for updating inline images. (`org-redisplay-inline-images`)

Combine these two and you should be good to go!

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-redisplay-inline-images)
```

[image: C-c C-c updating inline images]

Comment: Great, it works also. BTW, is org-babel-after-execute-hook for all org command or just for this command? maybe I only wish to hook C-c C-c command but not others!

Comment: This hook will only affect code blocks in Org buffers. Actually, if you wanted to do more then that, you would need to do a bit of extra work.

Comment: WOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU!